# Google Chrome applying color profile to Facebook images?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, internet-explorer, color-profiles

It seems that Google Chrome is applying some sort of color profile to Facebook images, which makes the color gamut look "off." If I open the same Facebook images in Internet Explorer 10, the images appear quite "normal."

As a test outside of Facebook, I pulled up a random photo via a Google Image search of the Bahamas, in both IE10 and Chrome. The photo looked similar in both web browsers, so it appears that the issue only happens on the Facebook website in the Google Chrome browser, but **not** Facebook in Internet Explorer.

- IE Version: 10.0.9200.16466
- Chrome: Version 23.0.1271.97 m
- OS: Windows 8 Professional
- Video card: AMD Radeon HD5850
- Video driver: 9.2.0.0
- LCD Panels: Acer P235H

Any ideas on what's going on, and how to remove the custom color profiling from Google Chrome, or Facebook (not sure who's actually doing it).

Comment: Color Management in [FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox), [IE](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/colorprofiles/default.html) & [Chrome](http://photographylife.com/chrome-color-management). I've never heard of any browser treating sites differently when it comes to color management. Maybe the random img you tested wasn't tagged properly? See if these test pages help: [1](http://www.petapixel.com/2012/06/25/is-your-browser-color-managed), [2](http://www.gballard.net/psd/go_live_page_profile/embeddedJPEGprofiles.html), [3](http://bit.ly/4eEELD).

Comment: Thanks for the test pages. I just tried them out, and both IE10 and Chrome 23 are most definitely color managed. One important thing to note: Google Chrome does NOT support ICC version 4 color profiles, however Internet Explorer 10 does. I believe that is link #3 in your comment. So, there is definitely something different about the two browsers ...

Comment: Whatever Chrome does or does not support, no link I've read so far suggests that it would behave differently on different pages. So it might be Facebook to blame after all, but I'm not sure how.